# Node.Js Mean Stack, Save method always return "User Already Exists"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, meanjs

I am learning NodeJs Mean Stack and was working with Mean.Js sample app,
Everything works fine and I am able to create first user with the sign up form. But creating another user always give me "User name Alreay Exists" message. I've applied check on the code before save to see if user already exists ore not and mongoose findOne method returns me null(and he is right because user with the provided username does not exist) but save method still gives error, user already exist

here is my sign up code:

```
/**
 * Signup
 */
exports.signup = function(req, res) {
    // For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
    delete req.body.roles;

    // Init Variables
    var user = new User(req.body);

    var message = null;

    // Add missing user fields
    user.provider = 'local';
    user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

    User.findOne({
        "username": user.username
    }, function(oerr, dbUser) {
        if (oerr) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) + ' user Name' + user.username
            });
        }
        if (dbUser === null) {
            // Then save the user
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) + ' user Name' + user.username
                    });
                } else {
                    // Remove sensitive data before login
                    user.password = undefined;
                    user.salt = undefined;

                    req.login(user, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(400).send(err);
                        } else {
                            res.json(user);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: "This User Already Exist Buddy. " + ' user Name' + user.username
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you see what happens if you move lines 8-15 to just before line 27? In other words: first check to see if a user exists. If it doesn't exist, then create a new user and save it. You seem to be creating a new user (although you don't save it), then checking to see if it exists.

Comment: shifting code near to save call does not change anything. In fact I injected the findOne method to see if the username already exists or not. Interestingly, findOne method correctly returns null(User does not exist) but save method complains that user already exists. It does save the record for first time(When there is no record in user schema)

Comment: Try changing the === to ==? What happens if you log dbUser?

Comment: nothing. In fact there is only one record in db with username="test@test.com.pk". I can see this through mongodb-ui-client tool

Comment: So dbUser is empty but not null?

Comment: dbUser is null. It is not null when I set username="test@test.com.pk"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83803/discussion-between-zafaryousafi-and-veggiesaurus).

Comment: Its my bad. I renamed the field username to userName and then back to username. Mongodb has kept the field userName in his schema and it always complains about userName field not username field. Anyway thanks @veggiesaurus